# Get values from received html body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to get the body values from received html request body using Spring boot:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/notification")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotifications(
            @RequestParam(value = "uniqueid", required = false)) String uniqueidValue,
            @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false)) String statusValue) {

        // Get values from html body

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

For example when I receive into the notification body:

```
some_key=some_value&sec_key=sec_value
```

I would like to parse the values. How I can implement this?

Comment: look at `@RequestBody`

Comment: That's what RequestParam does. Replace uniqueid by some_key, and type by sec_key.

Comment: Can I implement some filter?

Comment: Probably. But if you want a more precise answer, you should ask a more precise question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the key value pair request with using Map and @RequestBody as below:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/notification")
public ResponseEntity handleNotifications(@RequestBody Map<String,String> keyValuePairs) {
    // here you can use keyValuePairs
    // you can process some specific key like
    String value = keyValuePairs.get("someSpecificKey");

    return ResponseEntity.ok(value);
}
```

Here I attach example postman request : [image]

Comment: This will return Map?

Comment: How I can implement some filter? For example I want only specified keys?

Comment: This belongs to you, I will edit my answer to show u return map and example request.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to access specific key and I attached example postman request screenshot.